# Any blogs,articals or docs to learn AKKA Remote internals?

Tags: akka, akka.net, akka-cluster, akka-remote-actor, akka-remoting

Any blogs,articals or docs to learn AKKA Remote internals,indepth working how actor created how all connected how messages shared?

1. Endpoint Reader,Writer,Endpoint Manager
2. Association handler,
3. Message Dispatcher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a YouTube video about Akka.Remote's internals many years ago and it's still pretty accurate, even though we've refactored and performance-optimized the internals many times since:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6c1gVLyYcMM

Comment: Already watched i need to know the Endpoint Writer,Reader working and capabilities in more details

Comment: Next best thing to do is to read the source code then